# compare value of $.post in jquery captcha validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

hi i had written code for captcha validation but it not works, what am i missing

```
 function validate() {

     $.post("http://localhost/test/captch.php?captcha=" + document.getElementById("captchaid").value, function (data) {
         alert("sss" + data);
         if (data != 'yes') {
             alert("invalid captcha");
             return false;
         }

     });
 }
```

Comment: What exactly *doesn't work*? how do we know if your captcha.php script returns `yes` or not?

Comment: my form gets submitted evend if value of captcha.php is yes or no

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577632/validating-and-submitting-a-form-using-javascript-ajax . Your `.post` call is asynchronous, so the browser will send the ajax request, but will not wait for an answer before continuing. Thus, your form gets submitted. Also, the `return false` is in the context of the callback function and not `validate`.